# jQuery disable form submit in less than xx seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, form-submit

I have a user registration form.I need to check if user form filled in less than xx seconds(5 seconds). If less than 5 seconds disable the form submit. Some thing like that disable the submit button click or return false or like that.

I wrote some jquery scripts.But not correctly working.

Here is the sample form.

```
<form id="registerform" class="registerform" method="post"/>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the jquery scripts.

```
<script type=javascript>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 

     var typingTimer;    //timer identifier
     var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

     var checktime = 0;

     jQuery('form#registerform').find(':input').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).keyup(function(){
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });

        jQuery(this).keydown(function(){
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        });

    });



    function doneTyping () {
        checktime = typingTimer;
        return checktime;
    }

    jQuery('form#registerform').submit(function() {
        checktime = doneTyping ();
        var timerInsec = (doneTypingInterval/1000);
        if(checktime < timerInsec) {
            return false; // disable form submit
        } else {
             // if user take to fill the form more than 5 seconds, submit the form
            return true; 
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I need to integrate to the wordpress registration form.That's why I tried.
If anyone have a solution/solutions to this please help me. Really appreciate that.

Thank you

Comment: Sumith, you must also add server-side validation. Please take a look at my answer! If you have any questions, go ahead and ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will disable your submit button for 5 seconds:

```
var submitButton = $('#submitBtn');
submitButton.prop("disabled", true);
setTimeout(function() {
   submitButton.prop("disabled", false);
}, 5000);
```

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/RZHLg/)

You would also want to make sure, that the malicious user doesn't submit the form by other means! Make sure to run server-side validation:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['last_submit_time']) ) {
    $delay  = intval($_SESSION['last_submit_time']) + 5;
    if ( time() < $delay ) {
          $_SESSION['last_submit_time'] = time();
          echo "You must wait for 5 more seconds before submitting. Timer reset.";
          exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: A spammer is still able to just submit the form, you'll have to check this on the server side. Moreover, what with forms with automatic input?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it's absolutely correct! Updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want how many times user get the fill the form and submit the form, that time if less than 5 seconds disable the form submit.like that process. Aim to stop spams.So I did like this using your jquery script. jQuery('form#registerform').find(':input').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).keyup(function(e){
   var submitButton = jQuery('form#registerform input[type="submit"]');
   submitButton.prop("disabled", true);
   e.preventDefault();
   
   setTimeout(function() {
      submitButton.prop("disabled", false);
   }, 5000);
  });
 });   So it worked.

Comment: If I integrate this to WordPress registration form, what is the last_submit_time ?  That value is adding to session when form is submitting ?  Thank you

Comment: Yes, this part of code should be put to your form processor. You should modify it to content your needs and make user-friendly notifications.

Answer (score 0):

typing timer does not contain the time , instead it contains an id for the timer thats currently ticking...and since key up will always set it to some value, it will never be false.
Also, you add add and reset timer for each input. If you want the user to spend at least 5 seconds to fill in your form, dont enable the submit button until 5 sec has passed.

```
function doneTyping () {
    checktime = typingTimer;//will always have a value that evaluates to true
    return checktime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that... HTML:

```
<form id="registerform" class="registerform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    var intervalTime = 5000,
        inputID      = "#submit";



    function initialize(interval, input) { 
        intervalTime = interval;
        inputID      = input;

        jQuery(inputID).prop("disabled", true);        
        startCouting();
    }



    function startCouting() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            enableInput();
        }, intervalTime);
    }



    function enableInput() {
        jQuery(inputID).prop("disabled", false);
    };



    initialize(5000, "#submit");
});
```

Comment: This is disable the submit button 5 seconds from load the page. I want how many times user get the fill the form and submit the form, that time if less than 5 seconds disable the form submit.like that process. aim to stop spams. thanks